# Android Wear NullPointerException can't set text on TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, wear-os

I am trying to write an Android Wear application. For now I've got a TextView and would like to set the text programmatically.

```
private TextView mTextView;
private TextView text;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstance);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
  final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub)findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
  text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
  stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener((stub -> {
    mTextView = (TextView)stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
  }};

  text.setText("test");
}
```

When trying to run the application like that I get a nullpointerexception at

```
 text.setText("test");
```

That led me to assume that the TextView "text" was not found. Normally on Android phone applications it is just fine to call the

```
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Directly after

```
setContentView();
```

But now there are things like the WatchViewStub and the setOnLayoutInflatedListener. Maybe there's something I've overseen?

However, how do I specify my TextView correctly on the Android Wear platform?

**Edit**:

activity_my.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_my"
app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_my"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear">
</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

rect_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear_square">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

round_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear_round">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post `activity_my.xml`

Comment: @VenomVendor I just edited my post and added the xml files

Comment: Try to learn from here : http://ptrprograms.blogspot.in/2014/06/introduction-to-official-android-wear.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to code from your `Activity`:

```
private TextView mTextView;
private TextView text;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub)findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener((stub -> {
        mTextView = (TextView)stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }};

    text.setText("test");
}
```

Why do you have two `TextView`s? You have only one either in your `rect_activity:` or `round_activity:` layouts.

You have to understand how `WatchViewStub` works. You cannot access views from your rect/round layouts right after `setContentView` because they are not inflated yet. Like you did - you can access your views only in `OnLayoutInflatedListener` listener callback.
You have tried to find your `mTextView` inside this callback - which is the way you should do it.

### What is wrong?

You should remove following lines:

```
  text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

and this one: (it also causes your `NullPointerException`)

```
  text.setText("test");
```

and keep only the `mTextView` field.

### What should you do?

Add following like right after `mTextView = (TextView)stub.findViewById(R.id.text);`:

```
  mTextView.setText("test");
```

It must be incide the `OnLayoutInflatedListener`.

Your final code should look like:

```
private TextView mTextView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub)findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener((stub -> {
        mTextView = (TextView)stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        mTextView.setText("test");
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have **TextView** in `activity_my.xml`

<strike>`text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);`</strike>

Comment: So how do I access the TextView in round_activity or rect_activity?

Answer (score 0):

if rect_activity.xml and round_activity.xml are for different activities then you need to create new activities and call setContentView for those xml 
Only after that you can use the views in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding an `OnLayoutInflatedListener` you can extend `InsetActivity` and set your content view in `InsetActivity.onReadyForContent()`:

`import android.support.wearable.activity.InsetActivity;
public class MainActivity extends InsetActivity {
...
    @Override
    public void onReadyForContent() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        someTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_field);`